# Manhwa or manga about a prince who is banished from his kingdom, but awakens a farm system and begins building a city in a cold freezing land

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I once read a manga or manhwa about a prince who is banished from his kingdom because he has low magic aptitude, but awakens a farm system. The prince was a reincarnated person and begins building his own city in a cold freezing land.

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white? Also, when you say that the prince was a reincarnated person, do you mean that he was transmigrated from another world?